# single sign on Onelogin through curl

Tags: curl, single-sign-on

I use single sign on (Onelogin) for a corporate website and want to access the website through curl. However, curl simply redirects me to the onelogin page, even if I've already authenticated through my browser. Is there a cookie stored on my computer that I can provide to curl?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your browser and the process you're calling curl from can exchange cookies OneLogin is not going to recognize that you've established a valid session at OneLogin.

You'd have the same issue if you logged in via one browser (say FF) and then tried to SSO in from another browser (say Chrome)